# 16.04 not booting and no console available. "A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up"

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade

I've seen other people having this issue and being related to video drivers. So there are a few solutions regarding removal and reinstallation of those drivers. The thing is, I can't get a console to type any commands. Pressing shift until grub shows up doesn't help, as it gets stuck and unresponsive at the GRUB screen and no keys work.

While in the "purple backround screen", pressing ctrl+alt+f1 shows "A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up". Sometimes I even got the Ubuntu logo to show up (with a screwed up resolution) and even the loading indicator (the dots changing color) but that's as far as it gets.

GRUB version is 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.2.

So, any other solutions available? Anything I can do to be able to type commands so I can try uninstalling video drivers?

Comment: You can use CTRL+ALT+F1 (up to F6) but before that a) please do not post dupes and b) EDIT this question and add detailed info regarding your hardware, especially the graphics, and what proprietary drivers have you installed before, if any.