# Manually restore graphics in my Ubuntu 16 that doesn't boot after upgrading from 14?

Tags: boot, nvidia

I detailed my problem here [16.04 not booting and no console available. "A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867161/16-04-not-booting-and-no-console-available-a-start-job-is-running-for-hold-unt) and I'm still unable to solve the problem. Basically, my computer never rebooted after the infamous upgrade from ubuntu 14 to ubuntu 16.

Since I'm unable to open a terminal, I got a bootable live usb stick, but I'm not sure how to modify anything from the "host" computer (instead of the RAM live versio I'm running) from there.

For instance, I've read that a solucion might be removing plymouth-gdm and replacing it with gdm. Or doing `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`. Or `sudo apt-get remove plymouth` and then `sudo apt-get purge nvidia`.

The thing is, since I don't have access to a terminal, I can't try any of these solutions. So I thought maybe I should boot up from the live usb stick and manually modify whatever these commands do on the system. Is that even possible? How can I find out what to modify?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [16.04 not booting and no console available. "A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/867161/16-04-not-booting-and-no-console-available-a-start-job-is-running-for-hold-unt)

Comment: Well, actually, now I'm asking how to manually run some commands. Since my other question was never answered and this one is more specific.

Comment: You should always edit the previous question, not post a dupe.

Comment: And you should describe your problem along with detailed relevant information (as commented in your first question) instead of asking for what you *think* is a solution (it isn't BTW).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was able to get the grub to work and system to boot.

The keyboard was disabled from BIOS. So I just went into the BIOS and from Integrated Peripherals enabled USB keyboard.
Then, once in GRUB screen, selected Ubuntu advanced options > recovery > root mode and from there I ran `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`. Selected *lightdm* and Ubuntu 16 booted.